# How to modify value of input field from on change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to format any input of an input field to be a currency:

```
<input
    type="text"
    value="0,00 EUR"
    onChange={(e) => {
        e.target.value = generateCurrency(e.target.value)
    }}
/>

const generateCurrency = (input) => {
    const formattedCurrency = // do something with input
    return formattedCurrency;
}
```

My issue is that the value of the input field does not change. Maybe `e.target.value = generateCurrency(e.target.value)` is not correct.

I am planning to let the user create multiple of that input fields. Thus I avoid using the state hook. I'm trying to do it directly from the onChange to that value. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define local state for it.

```
<input
    type="text"
    value={this.state.inputValues['text1']}
    onChange={(e) => {
        const value = generateCurrency(e.target.value)
        this.setState({ inputValues['text1']: value });
    }}
/>

const generateCurrency = (input) => {
    const formattedCurrency = // do something with input
    return formattedCurrency;
}
```

Comment: Is there any other solution, as I am planning to let the user create multiple of that input fields. Thus I'd need a dynamic state?! This is why I'm trying to do it directly from the onChange to that value.

Comment: You can have object or array in state

Answer (score 0):

De facto storing currencies means storing a number with 2 decimal places (`Number.prototype.toFixed(2)`). Attaching the currency symbol or other elements into the data structure item isn't a solid workaround as it would require to be parsed in order to perform operations or similar.

Adding a mask while rendering the input allow the amount to be displayed in a human readable way, without affecting data storing efficiency.

By storing this data into an array you're able to add a cell whenever you have an extra input that need this type of mask. Everything regarding the currency is managed inside the input itself.
I've added a constructor reference in the code below too.

```js
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { currencyValues: [] };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={e => {
          let res = this.state.currencyValues;
          res.push((e.target.value.split('€')[1] * 1).toFixed(2));
          this.setState({ currencyValues: res });
        }}
        value={`€${
          this.state
            .currencyValues[1] /* E.G. With 2 inputs you populate cells 0 and 1 of the Array */
        }`}
      />
    );
  }
```

Comment: This is not answering my question, or I don't get the point.

Comment: Just updated, if you still don't get the point I'd be happy to explain the logic behind the code.

Answer (score 0):

> I avoid using the state hook. I'm trying to do it directly from the
> onChange to that value. Is that possible?

I think **NO**, I am not sure about that.

But I highly recommend to not to avoid ***state's***.

So you just need to initialize the state constructer.

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
         currency: "0,00 EUR"
    };
}
```

Then change your `Input` tag as below.

```
<input
    type="text"
    value={this.state.currency}
    onChange={e => this.generateCurrency(e.target.value)}
/>
```

Then do the last thing just change your `generateCurrency` function.

```
const generateCurrency = (input) => {
     this.setState({
         currency: value
     });
}
```

Comment: I think this will only work if there is one single input field. But I'll have many.

Comment: What you want can please describe. Do you want the value of Many Input field?

Comment: As I wrote, I want to user to create multiple input fields. He clicks a button and a new input field appears with a currency. That's why I thought it makes sense to not use states and handle it from the onChange directly.